# Basic strpos, preg_match or even == does not work on new server

Tags: php, mysql

I recently migrated to a new server and some old scripts that were looking at strpos suddenly stopped working, I tried `preg_match and even == to look for specific words and it does not work`.

If I strip the entire script down to something like this, it works fine -

```
$searchTerm = "places to rent in seattle";
if (strpos($searchTerm, "rent") !== false) { echo "rent keyword found"; }
```

But it stops working if I put it into a MySQL loop over results -

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $searchTerm = $row["searchTerm"];
    if (strpos($searchTerm, "rent") !== false) { echo "rent keyword found"; }
}
```

It stops working for some reason. I've tried doing a basic var_dump of the results and they come out correct, I've checked that they're strings. As mentioned, I also tried replacing `strpos with preg_match and even == to look for the word rent to no success`.

Comment: not working means.... what error you got? paste here

Comment: That's the weird thing, I get no error. No error logs, nothing in debug. It simply does not match on the rent keyword and the rest of the script continues as normal